# Regular expression to combine two lines into one?

Tags: regex, powergrep

I am using PowerGrep to collect some data from html files. In every file I match two strings using regex, and then I want to combine that two strings into one line.

I tried to use:

```
$\r\n
```

and replace with blank but it won't work. When I use the same regex in Notepad++ it works. But I can't use Notepad++ to collect data from a lot of files at once.
Any hint how to combine two lines in PowerGrep?

This is what I have

```
aaa, 
bbb
```

Want this:

```
aaa,bbb
```

Comment: Remove `$`, use `\r\n`. Or `\r?\n`. Or `(?>\r\n?|\n)`

Comment: What do you mean by _combine 2 strings into 1 line_ ? Give an example.

Comment: @Wiktor thanks, tried them all in PowerGrep but dont work.

Comment: @sln I edited my question.

Comment: Are you sure these are really CRLF endings? Try `[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]+`

Comment: Probably there is a simple option called Multiline or something.

Comment: Yes, these are CRLF, I can select it as a character, but don't know how to remove it. I know it is simple but none of solutions work.

Comment: To _remove it_ as you say, requires a replacement. Like find `\r?\n` replace with nothing.